# Is it possible for a bicyclo compound to have three bridges of equal length?

Tags: organic-chemistry

My teacher told me that the value of $x$ is always greater than or equal to $y$ and that y is always greater than $z$ in a bicyclo compound, where $(x,y,z)$ are the lengths of the bridges.

[image: bicyclo-compound]

But in this compound $x = y = z$.
Can someone clarify?

Comment: That's when the _"or equal"_ part steps in.

Comment: Do you mean that z is equal to or less than y?

Comment: Yes, it should read like that.

Comment: For the ignorant among us what are the definitions of X, Y and Z?

Comment: The compound is bicyclo (4,4,4) tetradecane I think. So the x,y and z refer to the numbers 4,4, and 4 which are the number of carbons in each part of the rings excepting the two "anchor carbons." So for a different bicyclo compound you'd write (4,3,2), going high to low, not any other combination such as (3,2,4).

Answer (score 5):

Why not? The simplest bicyclic bridged compound, [bicyclo[1.1.1]pentane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicyclo(1.1.1)pentane), is a well-known example of such a molecule for its use in synthesizing the even more strained [propellane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.1.1-Propellane). I believe your teacher was trying to prescribe the rules of [bicyclic nomenclature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicyclic_molecule#Nomenclature), i.e.

> In between the prefix and the suffix, a pair of brackets with numerals denotes the number of carbon atoms between each of the bridgehead atoms. These numbers are arranged in descending order and are separated by periods.